# Thread-Safe hooking function

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, assembly, hook

I am implementing little monitoring application, so i am hooking CreateWindowExA/W in process, so i can control the windows creation.
The method i use to hook is to replace first 5 bytes from the call with assembler JMP instruction to my hook function. (Yes i know assembler, i used same method many times before).
I use EnterCriticalSection at beginning of my hook code and i use InterlockedExchange to restore the stolen bytes aka replacing the JMP i wrote at beginning of CreateWindowExA/W with the real 5 bytes so i can call the function correctly. According to my experience everything has to be fine, but what happen is that at the moment when i just replaced the JMP with the real bytes, some other thread/s call the function, looks like the bytes are replaced for them too....

I know i can use IAT/EAT tables hooking but i want to know whats wrong with my current method...
Maybe the problem that InterlockedExchange is not working is that, CreateWindowExA/W is called from dll's(comctl32.dll,shell32.dll...) but not the main executable module.

I hope someone help me, if you dont understand well my explanation please ask and i will re-explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are hooking windows functions, IAT hooks are far better and safer. however, if you  insist on using detours, its generally better to use the hotpatching builtin on the windows side of things (this makes writing of the detour atomically possible, requiring no synchronization).

Your problems is exactly as you say, your lock only suspends your thread(s) of execution, but not those controlled by you. to fix this you either need to suspend all those threads (via PSAPI/toolhlp32), or more efficiently, add a check to the function you detoured to that checks if the callee address lies in the address space of the modules you want detoured, this can be done with GetModuleHandle, some PE functions from WinNT and the `_ReturnAddress` intrinsic.

Comment: i want to hook calls from ALL modules, i dont get your point, suspending threads looks bad solution. Better to me looks to use simple length disassembler, just to get first few assembler instructions, to replace them with jmp and later on i wont restore them but push the params on the stack execute the stolen instructions and JMP to CreateWindowExA/W, the JMP will actually lead right after the JMP that leads to my code. Can someone confirm that on all OS's the first assembler instructions in every API are "MOV EDI,EDI","PUSH EBP","MOV EBP,ESP" ? (I know its not the case for ntdll.dll)

Comment: If i hook EAT of user32.dll and IAT of all other modules in the current process all will be fine, later on if new module get loaded, since i hooked EAT of user32.dll will the new module acquire address of my hook for CreateWindowEx/A/W ?

Comment: @VisaToHell: if you want the detour to apply to all modules in the current process(which is **not** what your question implies), you need only hotpatch the code in the system dll (that's what the `mov edi,edi` and preceding free bytes are for, no need for a RLD), as every process gets there own copy of the system dll. ensuring this occurs before anything else can use the functions generally requires a loader to start the process in a suspended state, or block its init till patching is complete.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you change back the bytes the hooking will be lost and a critical section won't help because this is after the jmp.

Have a look at http://dxhook.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dxhook.cpp in [DXHooks](http://code.google.com/p/dxhook/) as I think it'll do what you need

Comment: I looked at Windows Detours library, it looks good, i will try it out tonight, its capable of hooking IAT/EAT and directly patching first bytes right ? Are there any lacks or disadvantages of Detours library ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can control every single call to CreateWindowEx then you can wrap them with a critical section. However, if you could do that, then you would not need to hook the function.

What's left is to hook the function before any other threads have started. Do this right at the beginning of your application, possibly by using static initialization.

One other thought about this particular function. In many apps, all windows are created in the main thread. If that is so for you then you have no need to synchronize.